# Need to calculate total amount of tank filled per day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data from different tanks getting filled. A tank can be started filling at any point seems necessary from end user. I need to calculate the total of tank filled per day from this data.

```
User ID   Tank ID   tank_capacity   tank_percent_full   server_time
XXZFR170500033  01617IJT0526Z3  1000    96  2017-05-01T02:02:23.971Z
XXZFR170500033  01617IJT0526Z3  1000    95  2017-05-01T10:58:57.691Z
XXZFR170500033  01617IJT0526Z3  1000    95  2017-05-01T14:03:36.828Z
XXZFR170500052  01617IJT0528y3  1000    95  2017-05-19T18:13:04.327Z
XXZFR170500052  01617IJT0528y3  1000    94  2017-05-19T18:27:18.657Z
XXZFR170500052  01617IJT0528y3  1000    75  2017-05-20T13:53:25.142Z
XXZFR170500052  01617IJT0528y3  1000    74  2017-05-20T17:51:54.000Z
XXZFR170500039  01617IJT0528x3  1000    66  2017-05-24T12:41:16.659Z
XXZFR170500039  01617IJT0528x3  1000    69  2017-05-24T12:54:27.501Z
XXZFR170500039  01617IJT0528x3  1000    65  2017-05-24T13:12:02.007Z
```

Answer would look like this

```
XXZFR170500033 01617IJT0526Z3 2017-05-01 1% used 10 l
XXZFR170500052 01617IJT0526y3 2017-05-01 21% used 210 l
XXZFR170500039 01617IJT0526x3 2017-05-01 4% used 40 l
```

remember that the tank 01617IJT0526x3 started from 66 but rise to 69 , that means tank was getting filled for that time and we must ignore those and then when we see decline in percent total then only we take difference. so we will only take from 69 to 65 in our calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the fills by using `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(tank_percent_full) over (partition by tank_id order by server_time) as prev_tank_percent_full
      from t
     ) t
where prev_tank_percent_full < tank_percent_full;
```

It is a little unclear what result you actually want beyond this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would like to get sum of difference between  each highest tank fill and lowest tank level before it started filling for one day. refer to the lower portion of my question for answer

Comment: Your answers partially solves the problem , what can be done further is take difference individually and add 0 wherever prev is > present , and finally take sum of everything.